# how to extract a spectrogram signal from accelerometer signals stored in text file?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, signal-processing, accelerometer, spectrogram

i try to convert my accelerometer signal (x-axis) and (y-axis) and (z-axis) into spectrogram by calculating the magnitude

the dataset is divided into three text files for x,y and z respectively each file contains one column and 1000 rows.

and this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fake_size = 1000
time = np.arange(fake_size)/1000 # 1kHz

x = np.loadtxt("trainingdatasetX.txt", delimiter=",")
y = np.loadtxt("trainingdatasetY.txt", delimiter=",")
z = np.loadtxt("trainingdatasetZ.txt", delimiter=",")

xyz_magnitude = x**2 + y**2 + z**2

to_plot = [('x', x), ('y', y), ('z', z), ('xyz', xyz_magnitude)]

for chl, data in to_plot:
    plt.figure(); plt.title(chl)
    plt.specgram(data, Fs=1000)
    plt.xlabel('Time [s]'); plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.show()
```

but it gives me the following error

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\hadeer.elziaat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7221
    Z = 10. * np.log10(spec)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
```

Comment: I am surprised no one answered this... it seems like you have a value `0` in your data. When it tries to get the specgram using the equation `Z = 10. * np.log10(spec)` =`10. * np.log10(0)` . it warns you that `divide by zero encountered in log10`